# Inrush NTC thermistor vs. frequent on/off

Tags: temperature, switching, circuit-protection, thermistor, inrush-current

NTC thermistors has high resistance at normal temperature, thus limiting the effect of a surge of current during power-up. Its resistance lowers after itself heating up during normal operation, removing its influence.

If a device, say power electronics, gets quickly switched back on without properly cooling down from last cycle. The NTC thermistor might not have cooled down to have a high enough resistance to block the inrush. This is a valid scenario, and that's why frequency switching on and off shall be avoided, correct?

Comment: Your scenario is valid ... So, quickly switching (example) "domestic" devices should be avoided (not necessarily for the same reasons, but yes, perhaps also ... and especially where transformers are used at "full load")

Comment: I have never used NTCs for inrush limiting. But in other discussions, people have mentioned this issue, that the inrush limiting function is defeated if the device is toggled rapidly. So I think you are on the right track.